# How to finish the TLAPS proof for a refinement mapping involving records?

Tags: theorem-proving, tla+, tlaps

I have some difficulty in proving a refinement mapping involving records.
Below are the simplified illustrating [TLA specs@github](https://github.com/hengxin/tlaps-examples/tree/master/Record) (Note that this post is also in [tlaplus-googlegroup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tlaplus/rmmH9vFwH_0/rY18YWMGDQAJ), without replies yet.):

---

`SimpleVoting.tla:`

It maintains for each participant a `maxBal` which is a natural number.
In `IncreaseMaxBal(p, b)`, `maxBal[p]` is increased to a larger value `b`.

```
---------------------------- MODULE SimpleVoting ----------------------------
EXTENDS Naturals
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONSTANT Participant

VARIABLE maxBal

TypeOK == maxBal \in [Participant -> Nat]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Init == maxBal = [p \in Participant |-> 0]

IncreaseMaxBal(p, b) ==
  /\ maxBal[p] < b
  /\ maxBal' = [maxBal EXCEPT ![p] = b]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Next == \E p \in Participant, b \in Nat : IncreaseMaxBal(p, b)

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_maxBal
=============================================================================
```

---

`Record.tla:`

It maintains a 2D "array" `state`, where `state[p][q]` is the State of `q` from the view of `p` and a State is a record:
`State == [maxBal : Nat, maxVBal : Nat]`.

In `Prepare(p, b)`, `state[p][p].maxBal` is increased to a larger value `b`.

```
------------------------------- MODULE Record -------------------------------
EXTENDS Naturals, TLAPS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONSTANTS Participant  \* the set of partipants

VARIABLES state \* state[p][q]: the state of q \in Participant from the view of p \in Participant

State == [maxBal: Nat, maxVBal: Nat]

TypeOK == state \in [Participant -> [Participant -> State]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InitState == [maxBal |-> 0, maxVBal |-> 0]

Init == state = [p \in Participant |-> [q \in Participant |-> InitState]] 

Prepare(p, b) == 
    /\ state[p][p].maxBal < b
    /\ state' = [state EXCEPT ![p][p].maxBal = b]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Next == \E p \in Participant, b \in Nat : Prepare(p, b)

Spec == Init /\ [][Next]_state
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Intuitively, `Record` maintains `maxBal[p]` of `SimpleVoting` as `state[p][p].maxBal`. Therefore, I want to show that `Record` refines `SimpleVoting` under the following refinement mapping:

```
maxBal == [p \in Participant |-> state[p][p].maxBal]

SV == INSTANCE SimpleVoting
```

However, step `<3>2` in the following proof fails.

```
THEOREM Spec => SV!Spec
  <1>1. Init => SV!Init
    BY DEF Init, SV!Init, maxBal, InitState
  <1>2. [Next]_state => [SV!Next]_maxBal
    <2>1. UNCHANGED state => UNCHANGED maxBal
      BY DEF maxBal
    <2>2. Next => SV!Next
      <3> SUFFICES ASSUME NEW p \in Participant, NEW b \in Nat,
                          Prepare(p, b)
                   PROVE  SV!IncreaseMaxBal(p, b)
        BY DEF Next, SV!Next
      <3>1. maxBal[p] < b
        BY DEF Prepare, maxBal
      <3>2. maxBal' = [maxBal EXCEPT ![p] = b] \* failed here!
        BY DEF Prepare, maxBal
      <3>3. QED
        BY <3>1, <3>2 DEF SV!IncreaseMaxBal
    <2>3. QED
      BY <2>1, <2>2
  <1>3. QED
```

The obligation at `<3>2` is as follows. Isn't the `state' = [state EXCEPT ![p] = ...]` in the assumption the same as the conclusion `[p_1 \in Participant |-> state[p_1][p_1].maxBal]' ...`? What is missing? What is wrong with my proof?

```
ASSUME NEW CONSTANT Participant,
       NEW VARIABLE state,
       NEW CONSTANT p \in Participant,
       NEW CONSTANT b \in Nat,
       /\ state[p][p].maxBal < b
       /\ state'
          = [state EXCEPT
               ![p] = [state[p] EXCEPT
                         ![p] = [state[p][p] EXCEPT !.maxBal = b]]] 
PROVE  [p_1 \in Participant |-> state[p_1][p_1].maxBal]'
       = [[p_1 \in Participant |-> state[p_1][p_1].maxBal] EXCEPT ![p] = b]
```